# React element change state from dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-automation

I have been using this function:

```js
window.FindReact = function (dom) {
  for (var key in dom) {
    if (key.startsWith('__reactInternalInstance$')) {
      var compInternals = dom[key]._currentElement;
      var compWrapper = compInternals._owner;
      var comp = compWrapper._instance;
      return comp;
    }
  }
  return null;
};
var someElement = $x("someElement")[0];
window.FindReact(someElement).setState({
  hover: true
});
```

To hover over elements in our website but since React 16, this is broken with an error

> 'VM25001:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_owner' of undefined at window.FindReact (:1:181) at :3:18'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, they no longer expose React internals in React 16. Your only option is to downgrade to React 15 at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the logic to manipulate state from the DOM from inside React:

```
constructor() {
  // A function to manipulate the state:
  this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);

  const domElementToManipulateState = document.getElementById('domElement');

  domElementToManipulateState.addEventListener('hover', this.changeState);
}
```